# Get request length limit in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari

I am using Omniture SiteCatalyst in my iPhone app.It uses get request to hit the servers internally via its sdk.However i am facing an issue where some of the request are not reaching the Omniture servers.The get request which is being sent is of variable length depending on the type of request(around 900 + characters).
My question is whether there any limit for the get request length in an iOS app? and if yes
how it would behave in case the request crosses the  limit?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically if URL conforms to RFC 2396 it is fine. According to documentation

> The NSURL class fails to create a new NSURL object if the path being
>   passed is not well-formed; the path must comply with RFC 2396.
>   Examples of cases that will not succeed are strings containing space
>   characters and high-bit characters. Should creating an NSURL object
>   fail, the creation methods return nil, which you must be prepared to
>   handle. If you are creating NSURL objects using file system paths, you
>   should use fileURLWithPath: or initFileURLWithPath:, which handle the
>   subtle differences between URL paths and file system paths. If you
>   wish to be tolerant of malformed path strings, you’ll need to use
>   functions provided by the Core Foundation framework to clean up the
>   strings.

But some time there is issue with specail character e.g. space, accents and others. You must `[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

It is also possible server could not handle very long urls, if there are any limitation on server, server will simple truncate the rest of url string, if this is an issue then server will return 414 error url too long.